# Laravel 4.2 Eloquent: How can i return the count of id based on the following query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4.2

### This is on my eloquent model.

```
public function getRecordCount($id = NULL){
            if ($id == 0) {
                $count = $this->leftJoin('liip_user_customers', 'warehouse_to', '=', 'liip_user_customers.customer_id')
                            ->where('status', '=', $id)
                            ->where('created_by_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                            ->select('id')
                            ->count('id');

                    if (!empty($count)) {
                        return $count;
                    }else{
                        return 0;
                    }
    }
}
```

---

This is on my controller.

```
public function getIndex(){
        $count_approval = $this->warehouse_transfer->getRecordCount(0);
        $count_correction = $this->warehouse_transfer->getRecordCount(14);
        $count_final = $this->warehouse_transfer->getRecordCount(13);
        $count_pending = $this->warehouse_transfer->getRecordCount(15);

        // Title
        $title = Lang::get('liipWarehousePalletTransfer::warehousePalletTransfer/title.warehouse_pallet_transfers_management');

        // Show the page
        return View::make('liipWarehousePalletTransfer::index', compact( 'title', 'count_approval', 'count_correction', 'count_close', 'count_disapprove', 'count_final', 'count_pending'));
}
```

And I got some error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' 
    in field list is ambiguous (SQL: select count(`id`) as aggregate from
    `liip_warehouse_pallet_transfers` left join `liip_user_customers` on
    `warehouse_to` = `liip_user_customers`.`customer_id` where `status` = 0
    and `created_by_id` = 159)
```

[Check the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWPNQ.jpg)

The badge in "For Approval" tab, should be "5".
I already searched about this problem, but i can't find same scenario like mine.

Comment: the error occurs because you are missing the column in the left join `warehouse_to.COLUMN`

Comment: @Miggy sir, "warehouse_to" is my column, by the way sir, the table handled by the Model named "liip_warehouse_pallet_transfers" and "warehouse_to" is column of "liip_warehouse_pallet_transfers" table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->leftJoin('liip_user_customers', 
        'warehouse_to', '=', 'liip_user_customers.customer_id')
```

The error occurs because you are missing the table name in your left join `TABLE_NAME.warehouse_to`

See [Laravel Join](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins) for more information

Comment: Miggy sir, "warehouse_to" is my column, by the way sir, the table handled by the Model named "liip_warehouse_pallet_transfers" and "warehouse_to" is column of "liip_warehouse_pallet_transfers" table.

Comment: It works sir! I added only "liip_warehouse_pallet_transfers" "liip_warehouse_pallet_transfers.warehouse_to"

Comment: @Kent sorry about the late reply, i thought `warehouse` to was your table name. Will change the answer accordingly

Comment: It's okay sir Miggy, :) and I appreciated your answer sir :)

Comment: Glad to help sir :) If it solves your question, you can mark my answer. Thanks